# How std::function<std::optional<T>()> is compatible with lambda returning T?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, std-function

I can create `std::function` that returns `std::optional<Foo>` and assigned lambda that returns `Foo` to it. Can someone explain in details how this is possible?

simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int k = 13;
    std::function<std::optional<int>()> f1;
    f1 = [&] {return k++;}; //implicite int
    std::cout<<"k = " << f1().value() << std::endl;
    f1 = [&] () -> int {return k;}; //explicite int
    std::cout<<"k = " << f1().value() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [constructor of `std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) (#8 in the overload set) is conditionally explicit, depending on the template parameter. In your case (`std::optional<int>`), you can implicitly construct instances,

```
std::optional<int> opt;

opt = 42; /* No problem, implicit construction. */
```

and this exactly is what the wrapper `std::function<std::optional<int>>` does. It calls the wrapped function, which returns an `int`, and uses this return value to implicitly construct its own return value, `std::optional<int>`.

Comment: I get main logic of your answer but examples are misleading. This question was not about implicite type conversion and second example with explanation below it is false. You can create `std::function<std::optional<A>>` that can be assigned by lambda returning A.

Comment: @Logman A lambda that returns an `A` instance works out just fine, but a lambda returning an `int` to construct an `A` doesn't work out. This is because of the conditionally explicit constructor of `std::optional`. This is what I tried to demonstrate with the last part.

Comment: I really get it, but as I said previously question was not to show how implicite conversion works, but to explain how std::function works. And you actually done this, but you also provide second example that is completely not important and misleading in context of this question.

Comment: @Logman Ok, I don't have an agenda to keep that second example snippet in the post, so as you consider it misleading,I took it out.

Answer (score 4):

There is an implicit conversion from `int` to `std::optional<int>`.

The template constructor of `std::function` uses the named requirement [*Callable*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Callable), which only requires that the `INVOKE` expression be implicitly convertible to the result type, not that they be the same type.

Answer (score 2):

In short the target assigned to `std::function` must me Callable for the parameters and return type of the  template parameter of `std::function`.

E.g. Given:

- a `std::function<R(P1, P2)>`
- `p1` of type `P1`
- `p2` of type `P2`

You can assign a target `f` to it if `f(p1, p2)` is well-formed and implicitly convertible to `R`. (*)

The other answers show that `std::optional<int>` is implicitly constuctible from `int`.

So in your example `[&] () -> int {return k;}()` returns an `int` and that is implicitly convertible to `std::optional<int>`.

*(*) Please note that this is a bit oversimplified as the rigorous definition involves the invoke function/concept*